# Styles.css Not Found for .NET Core Angular App in Linux

Tags: angular, nginx, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04

I have followed Microsoft's [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) to set up a .NET Core web application with an Nginx reverse proxy on Ubuntu 18.04.

I initially generated a generic web app using `dotnet new web` and it worked just fine. I could access the page with the server's public IP.

I then proceeded to generate an Angular app using `dotnet new angular`. I commented out `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` in Startup.cs to avoid redirect issues, ran `dotnet publish` and then ran the app. When I access the site publicly, I can see that index.html is served but all the other 4 files that are generated by webpack (js and css files) are not. I'm getting 404 (Not Found) errors.

I tried several different approaches to fix it, including changing/removing the base href in index.html, moving the 4 files to different locations, running `ng serve` for the Angular source files, etc. I don't have an RDP connection to the Linux box so haven't tried accessing the page directly rather than through the Nginx reverse-proxy.

Could not replicate the issue on Windows. It works fine both through the command prompt and using Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you sure the CSS files have been deployed? What is the URL being asked for?

Comment: Yeah, I can see the files. Once published, they go under ClientApp/dist. When I browse to the public IP of the server, index.html is served and the JS & CSS files are expected to be under the same location. e.g. http://123.123.123.123/main.165dfaf1ba6d8d3f4f7c.bundle.js